# The difference between deb versus deb-src in sources.list

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I don't understand the difference between these two lines in my sources.list, please explain:

`deb http://mirror.optus.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free`

versus

`deb-src http://mirror.optus.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free`

System: Debian 6 testing, 32 bit.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`deb` lines are relative to binary packages, that you can install with `apt`.

`deb-src` lines are relative to source packages (as downloaded by `apt-get source $package`) and next compiled.

Source packages are needed only if you want to compile some package yourself, or inspect the source code for a bug. Ordinary users don't need to include such repositories.

Comment: So if I only ever install packages by Synaptic or apt-get install, I only need the first line, `deb...` and not `deb-src...`?

Comment: @ptrcao: correct

Comment: Unless you want to manually compile packages (not *nearly* as beneficial as gentoo users like to think) or explicitly modify a few source files before compiling to suit your specific system's needs, you're fine with just the `deb ...` lines.