# How to manage Debian source code packages using aptitude or apt?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, source

Background: I would like to regularly download and install source to `/usr/src` for certain important development packages.  (For me: Qt5 and friends.)

I have seen [this other question about one-time downloads of Debian source packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121041/how-to-download-debian-packages-source-code).  However, one-time downloads of Debian source packages will not keep source code current each time the associated binary package is updated.

Example: Package `qtbase5-dev` has source package `qtbase-opensource-src`.  Each time package `qtbase5-dev` changes, the source package will not be automatically downloaded and installed into `/usr/src`.

Is there an existing way to do this using `aptitude` (preferrably) or `apt`?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to clone the [git repo](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-kde/qt/qtbase.git) for the package and run `git pull` periodicly?

Comment: You could probably write a script to check periodically against the Debian package system online. I think they have an api - https://wiki.debian.org/qa.debian.org/pts/SoapInterface

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do all you're asking for with `aptitude` or `apt`, but [`apt-src`](https://packages.debian.org/apt-src) provides `apt`'s features for source packages:

```
apt-src update
apt-src install package
apt-src upgrade
```

will respectively update the information on available packages, install `package`'s source code, and upgrade the source code if necessary.

Other options are available to build the packages from source after installation, remove source code etc.

By adding `apt` hooks you could configure your system so that the source code of packages you install is automatically downloaded and upgraded.