# What is the most managable way to install a program from source in Debian?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, compiling

Let's say that I've found a program that I want to install on my machine. It is only available as a source tarball that can be built with the usual ./configure; make; make install.

While I could do `make install` in these instances, I'm likely not going to know where xyz file/command come from in a few years, and whether it is important. And who knows what will happen if I try to build a newer version of the program.

What's the most common, manageable way of handling scenarios like this?

Comment: Look at CheckInstall: https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall

Comment: Another option is to install it under a prefix like `/usr/local/<program-name>` or `/opt/<program-name>`. You'll have to modify some environment variables like PATH to get it work though, but the advantage is you know exactly what is installed by the package.

Comment: Related: [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202371/125388) had asked on "How to manage Debian source code packages using aptitude or apt?", which had an answer for using `apt-src`. Just one of the ways, but may be not the best.

Comment: also look at `dh-make` and/or `debhelper` - tools that make it easy to build a package from unpackaged source code.