# How to debug an installed Qt5 library with GDB?

Tags: debugging, qt

Background: I am programming with Qt5 and want to debug the core Qt5 libraries on Debian using GDB.

I have installed all the necessary `-dev` and `-dbg` packages.  When I try to debug, GDB complains that the source code is not found.

How to install source code and use within GDB?

Answer (score 9):

I am answering my own question.  This was harder than I expected, and I want to gather all the information in one convenient place.

## Install Binary, Development, and Debug Packages

This can be done using `apt` (or `aptitude`).

Example for Qt5:

- Compiled libraries: `qt5-default`
- Development package (headers): `qtbase5-dev`
- Debugging symbols: `qtbase5-dbg`

## Find Source Package Name

You can find it using `aptitude` or the Debian package search tool: https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages

Example: Searching for `qtbase5-dbg` will find: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/qtbase5-dbg

The top of each binary package page has a link to the source package.

Example: `qtbase-opensource-src`

## Install Source Package

If necessary, first configure your `apt` source package repositories by reading this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121042/29414

1. Drop root: `su -`
2. `cd /usr/src`
3. `apt-get source ${source_package_name}`

   - Example: `apt-get source qtbase-opensource-src`
4. The source package is downloaded, unzipped/untarred, and patched into a new directory.

   - Example: `/usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.2+dfsg/`
5. Remove the downloaded TAR ball and other files (maybe `.dsc`). 
   `rm *.tar.* *.dsc`
6. Create a symbolic link: `ln -s qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.2+dfsg qtbase-opensource-src`

## Configure GDB

(This section can be completed using your non-root / regular account.)

GDB needs configuration to know where source code can be found.

Each source package is a little different, so I will use Qt5 as an example.

1. `cd /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src`
2. Find list of source subdirectories: 
   `find $(pwd) -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

   - Example: `/usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/corelib ...`
3. Reformat the `find` output to create GDB commands: 
   `find $(pwd) -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | xargs -l -i printf -- 'directory %s\n' "{}"`

   - Example: `directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/3rdparty ...`
4. Insert GDB commands into your `~/.gdbinit` for convenience.

Sample `~/.gdbinit`:

```
set auto-load safe-path /
set history save
set history filename ~/.gdb_history

directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/3rdparty
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/android
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/angle
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/concurrent
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/corelib
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/dbus
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/gui
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/network
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/opengl
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/openglextensions
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/platformsupport
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/plugins
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/printsupport
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/sql
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/testlib
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/tools
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/widgets
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/winmain
directory /usr/src/qtbase-opensource-src/src/xml
show directories
```

## Run GDB

This section assumes you already have a program compiled with debugging symbols linked to the library of interest, e.g., Qt5.

1. `gdb ${program_name}`
2. Start the program and break at `main()` automatically: `start`
3. Set a breakpoint in a library function: `b '${function_signature}'` 
   Command `b(reakpoint)` with single quotes supports (very impressive!) tab completion.

   - Example: `b 'QStyled<tab>` 
      -> `b 'QStyledItemDelegate` 
      -> `::paint(<tab>` 
      -> `b 'QStyledItemDelegate::paint(QPainter*, QStyleOptionViewItem const&, QModelIndex const&) const'`
4. Continue to hit the new breakpoint: `c` or `continue`
5. When the library breakpoint is hit, GDB will find and display the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Unfortunately, the package `qtbase5-dbg` does not exist outside Ubuntu 16 :/

Comment: @Xerus: I agree.  The latest Debian also does not have debug package.  I had to rebuild from the same source package above.  I built with full debug symbols and disabled all compiler optimizations.  It is a huge task.  When the libraries are installed, your Qt programs will run about 10x slower.  Eh.  I'll create another question soon (and self-answer) to explain the full process.

Comment: @kevinarpe Sorry for rushing you, but soon will be when? There is no package with '-dbg' postfix in Ubuntu 22 and i'm stuck with profiling my application.