# Update version of Kali Linux to 2020.3 from 2020.1

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I am trying to update my Kali version to 2020.3 from 2020.1 as I have many important files and tools installed, but I was not able to do it.

I consulted this site https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/updating-kali/

I tried `sudo apt full-upgrade` but nothing happened. The version is still 2020.1.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2020.1
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  clang-9 libclang-common-9-dev libclang-cpp9 libz3-dev llvm-9 llvm-9-dev llvm-9-runtime llvm-9-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  clang libomp-8-dev libomp5-8 libpocl2 libpocl2-common pocl-opencl-icd
6 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 47.2 MB/61.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 310 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 https://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpocl2 amd64 1.4-6 [15.8 MB]
Get:2 https://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpocl2-common all 1.4-6 [79.2 kB]
Get:3 https://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libz3-dev amd64 4.8.7-4 [87.3 kB]
Get:4 https://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 llvm-9-runtime amd64 1:9.0.1-9 [212 kB]
Get:5 https://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 llvm-9 amd64 1:9.0.1-9 [4,850 kB]
Get:6 https://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 llvm-9-tools amd64 1:9.0.1-9 [328 kB]
Get:7 https://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 llvm-9-dev amd54 1:9.0.1-9 [25.9 MB]
Fetched 39.9 MB in 13s (2,990 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libclang-ccp9.
(Reading database ... 251246 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libclang-ccp9_1%3a9.0.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libclang-cpp9 (1:9.0.1-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libclang-common-9-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libclang-common-9-dev_1%3a9.0.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libclang-common-9-dev (1:9.0.1-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package clang-9.
Preparing to unpack .../02-clang-9_1%3a9.0.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking clang-9 (1:9.0.1-9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-clang_1%3a9.0-49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking clang (1:9.0-49) over (1:8.0-48.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libomp-8-dev_1%3a8.0.1-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libomp-8-dev (1:8.0.1-8) over (1:8.0.1-4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libomp5-8_1%3a8.0.1-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libomp5-8:amd64 (1:8.0.1-8) over (1:8.0.1-4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-pocl-opencl-icd_1.4-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pocl-opencl-icd:amd64 (1.4-6) over (1.3-10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libpocl2_1.4-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ibpocl2:amd64 (1.4-6) over (1.3-10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libpocl2-common_1.4-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ibpocl2-common (1.4-6) over (1.3-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libz3-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libz3-dev_4.8.7-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libz3-dev:amd64 (4.8.7-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package llvm-9-runtime.
Preparing to unpack .../10-llvm-9-runtime_1%3a9.0.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking llvm-9-runtime (1:9.0.1-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package llvm-9.
Preparing to unpack .../11-llvm-9_1%3a9.0.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking llvm-9 (1:9.0.1-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package llvm-9-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../12-llvm-9-tools_1%3a9.0.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking llvm-9-tools (1:9.0.1-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package llvm-9-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../13-llvm-9-dev_1%3a9.0.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking llvm-9-dev (1:9.0.1-9) ...
Setting up libz3-dev:amd64 (4.8.7-4) ...
```

```
$ grep Version /etc/os-release
VERSION="2020.1"
VERSION_ID="2020.1"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
```

```
$ sudo apt full-uprade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

`sources.list` below

```
deb http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

I could still install a fresh Kali 2020.3, but it will take a lot of time to download and install all the tools. I have a really slow internet.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the mirror `http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali`. At the moment, it has an older snapshot of the Kali Linux repository. For example, its `base-files` version is 1:2020.1.0 while in Kali Linux 2020.3 it is 1:2020.3.1. That is why you cannot upgrade to 2020.3 with your configuration now.

[According to kali.org wiki](https://www.kali.org/docs/community/kali-linux-mirrors/), your `sources.list` should contain *only* the default host, which will redirect `apt` to the nearest up-to-date mirror automatically:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Change your `sources.list` to that one line and try again.

---

That single line in `sources.list` should be enough. You could also add another line for programs' source code [as explained at kali.org](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/#source-repositories). The lines in `sources.list` which start with `deb` are for pre-compiled binary packages, which are ready to run. The lines which start with `deb-src` are for source code, which you have to compile into binary before running. If you wonder whether you need that, you, likely, don't. The difference between `deb` and `deb-src` lines in `sources.list` [was also explained before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20504/423679).